# Best way to track emails - UUID vs ID number

Tags: email, guid, tracking, uuid, auto-responder

need to track 1 million email addresses within our organisation for marketing and customer response. It has been decided to develop in-house.

having done a little research into what others are doing I have noticed that all seem to use uuid (guid) for tracking. Is this the best way to track email activity?

Any other advice before we get cracking?

Answer (score 0):

UUID has the advantage that they can be generated by many machines independent of each other and they will not clash.  Using an ID number you need some way to make sure that the ids generated do not clash.  If you are doing this on a single machine, it may be simple.  If you wish to distribute this work, then you may need to think a little more about it. ID's have the advantage that they can be numeric and so are smaller to store in the DB, and can also imply some ordering.  Implying ordering is more difficult with GUIDs ([although not impossible](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2010/09/28/sequential-guid-algorithm-ndash-implementing-combs-in-.net.aspx))

If it was me, I'd just go with a GUID, it'll probably be simpler in the long run.